# php send email form with attachment(s) validate the size and extensions

Tags: php, forms, validation, email-attachments

I have made this code and i have now run my head against the wall.

It seems that the code cannot valide neither the size or the extensions of the file!

I do receive the file and the email. Can someone please explain me why my validation fails?

```
    <?php
//Get the uploaded file information
$name_of_uploaded_file =
    basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

//get the file extension of the file
$type_of_uploaded_file =
    substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
    strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

$size_of_uploaded_file =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

//Settings
$max_allowed_file_size = 2000; // size in KB
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "pdf");
$upload_folder = '../receivedfiles/';

//Validations
if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
{
  $errors .= "\n Fejl: Filen er for stor";
}

//------ Validate the file extension -----
$allowed_ext = false;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
{
  if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
  {
    $allowed_ext = true;
  }
}

if(!$allowed_ext)
{
  $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
  " Send venligst filer af følgende type: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
}

//copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
$path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
$tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
{
  if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
  {
    $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
  }
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$hesteid = $_POST['hesteid'];
$hestenavn = $_POST['hestenavn'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$formcontent=" Fra: $company \n Navn: $name \n Adresse: $adress , $areacode \n Land: $land \n Telefon: $phone \n Ringes op: $call \n Type: $type \n Hoppens navn og ID: $hestenavn , $hesteid \n Besked: \n $message \n Vedhæftede filer: \n $path_of_uploaded_file";
$recipient = "my@email.dk";
$subject = "Besked fra hjemmesiden";
$mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: /thank_you.shtml')
?>
```

HTML formcode:

```
    <form class="contactform" action="php/mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="company">Firma</label>
<input type="text" name="company" id="company" />
<label for="name">Navn</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Dit navn" id="name" required="required" /><span class="red">&#42;</span>
<br />
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="din@mail.dk" id="email" required="required" /><span class="red">&#42;</span>
<br />
<label for="phone">Telefon</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="012345678" id="phone" required="required" /><span class="red">&#42;</span>
<br />
<label for="adress">Adresse</label>
<input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="Din adresse" id="adress" />
<br />
<label for="areacode">Postnummer og By</label>
<input type="text" name="areacode" placeholder="Postnummer og By" id="areacode" />
<br />
<label for="land">Land</label>
<input type="text" name="land" placeholder="Land" id="land" />
<br />
<br />
<label for="call">Vil De ringes op?<span class="red">&#42;</span></label>
<table class="callme">
<tr>
<td class="callmetext"><p>Ja</p></td>
<td class="callmecheck"><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="call" id="call" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="callmetext"><p>Nej</p></td>
<td class="callmecheck"><input type="radio" value="Nej" name="call" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<label for="type">Emne</label>
<select name="type" size="1" id="type" required="required">
<option value="">Vælg fra listen</option>
<option value="Bestille dek&#230;ning">Bestille bedækning</option>
<option value="Bestille brochure">Bestille brochure</option>
<option value="Information om en hingst">Information om en hingst</option>
<option value="Information om stutteriet">Information om stutteriet</option>
<option value="Information om salgsheste">Information om salgsheste</option>
<option value="Information om Afkomsformidling">Information om afkomsformidling</option>
<option value="Information om samarbejdspartnere">Information om vore samarbejdspartner</option>
<option value="Andet">Andet</option>
</select><span class="red">&#42;</span>
<br />
<label for="hesteid">Hoppens ID</label>
<input type="text" name="hesteid" placeholder="208333DW..." id="hesteid" />
<br />
<label for="hestenavn">Hoppens navn</label>
<input type="text" name="hestenavn" placeholder="Hoppens navn..." id="hestenavn" />
<br />
<br />
<label for="message">Din besked<span class="red">&#42;</span></label>
<textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="20" placeholder="Skriv din besked her..." id="message" required="required"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<label for="uploaded_file">Vælg en fil:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<br />
<br />
<div class="center">
<label for="captcha">&#32;</label>
<div id="captcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="6LfnbiATAAAAAOBV8B7qaPGzfpyjdahePpyGhLjj"></div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="center">
<label for="submitBtn">&#32;</label>
<input class="contactbtn" type="submit" value="Send besked" id="submitBtn" disabled />
</div>
</form>
```

Bonus question: Will i be able to duplicate this code and change "uploaded_file" to "uploaded_file2", and 3, and so on and be able to add several more files?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. What kind of output does `print_r($_FILES)` produce?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with this command. How can i insert this?

Comment: It prints the contents of the `$_FILES` array. Just insert it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Midas, it doesn't show up with anything.

I have added "print_r($FILES);"

Comment: `$_FILES` not `$FILES` :)

Comment: Bummer, thanks :)

It says: "Array ( ) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/8/5/6/stutteri-volstrup.dk/httpd.www/php/mail.php:53) in /customers/8/5/6/stutteri-volstrup.dk/httpd.www/php/mail.php on line 71"

Comment: It's empty which means you didn't submit any file.

Comment: It submits file without the code? I get files in the upload folder without the code. Please advise :)

Comment: If you select a file in the form, then submit it, `print_r($_FILES)` should show all the details of the uploaded file. If it instead returns an empty array `Array ( )`, there is something wrong with your HTML form or server configuration. Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Hi again Midas
I get this message now and it also uploads to server. ´Array ( [uploaded_file] => Array ( [name] => 01-spitzer-omeganebula.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /customers/8/5/6/stutteri-volstrup.dk/tmp/phpDfCh5m [error] => 0 [size] => 748509 ) ) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/8/5/6/stutteri-volstrup.dk/httpd.www/php/mailtest2.php:53) in /customers/8/5/6/stutteri-volstrup.dk/httpd.www/php/mailtest2.php on line 71´

Form code also shown in topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular problem with your code. The only thing I noticed is that you aren't initializing `$error` anywhere, or checking its contents before sending the email.

Also, this entire block of code:

```
$allowed_ext = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
{
    if (strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i], $type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
    {
        $allowed_ext = true;
    }
}
```

... can be simplified as:

```
$allowed_ext = in_array(strtolower($type_of_uploaded_file), $allowed_extensions);
```

And to answer the bonus question: To implement multiple file uploads, you can use an array for your `input` names:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]">
```

Using `print_r` you can then figure out what this array looks like in PHP, and validate each file accordingly.

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); echo '</pre>';
```

After debugging, remember to remove any `echo` or `print_r` function calls that come before the `header` function. Otherwise you will receive the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm not sure on what to check. For the email i want to send the path and name of the file on the same time the script upload to the serverfolder. I can't see why errors should be initialized? Also i believe the code should come forth and tell if the file exceed the max limit or have a wrong extension?

Thanks for the rewriting on the script :)

Also thanks for the hint for the multiupload! I will go forth with that :)

Comment: @SimonJensen Enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and you will know why you need to initialize the `$error` variable. It will tell you you cannot append (`.=`) to a variable before it has been initialized. When error reporting is disabled, PHP will silently allow modifying uninitialized variables, but this is generally bad practice. Also, the code won't tell you anything about validation unless you tell PHP to print out the validation error. :)

Comment: I changed all the ´$errors´ to ´die´. That helped a lot. Next step is to make it a pop-up :)

I found out that i have no access to php.ini, so i couldn't render it there. But this helped a lot with troublesolving. I believe my new requirements exceed this thread. Thanks a bunch :)